# Domain problem issues, website needed updates, old code was deleted and replaced with the new one but still showing the old version

Tags: web, deployment

I uploaded files to my website few days ago. There were few errors to be fixed so I had to delete my files and uploaded updated version. somewhat I still see the old version of my page but not the new one. Desperately in need of help to fix this issue. Thanks a bunch in advance!

i tried to delete the filed multiple times and uploaded again but no changes happened. I also tried to view it on a firefox and safari but still the same. However, if I go live from VSCODE I can see the changes but not on the website

Comment: Could be caching, could be that you uploaded the wrong version of the files, could be you uploaded them to the wrong place. We have no access to your environment and so no real way of knowing what's happened or making much in the way of meaningful suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

(a) On your website, use a file manager tool to look at one of the files that was changed. Are the changes extant on the server? On a cPanel system, use the File Manager tool and click on one of the uploaded/changed files. There is an EDIT button on the top "toolbar" that will allow you to view the file.

(b) In your HTML, you might still be loading a cached version of the changed file, so the changes will not be visible to your browser. To fix that, add a query string to the end of the `src` attribute. For example,

From:

```
<script src="myfile.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="myfile.js?123abc"></script>
```

Any time you change that `123abc` value in your HTML, the document will be re-read from the server and not just fetched from cache.

This trick works for any type of file that is loaded from the file system, e.g.:

```
<img src="myupdatedlogo.jpg?asdf" />
```